# Reading memory protection

Tags: memory

I would like to know if there is for linux a way of retrieving the protection of the memory. Like, I want to restore the protection that existed after changing it with mprotect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the answer by davidg, here's the function `unsigned int read_mprotection(void* addr)`:
[re_mprot.c](https://github.com/18446744073709551615/reDroid/blob/master/jni/reDroid/re_mprot.c), [re_mprot.h](https://github.com/18446744073709551615/reDroid/blob/master/jni/re_mprot.h) from [the reDroid project at github](https://github.com/18446744073709551615/reDroid) (the code works on Android, it should be portable to other linuxes).

Answer (score 2):

The file `/proc/self/maps` on Linux contains information about the current layout of virtual memory, what each segment is and the memory protection of that segment. Changes made using `mprotect` will cause the file to be updated appropriately.

By parsing `/proc/self/maps` before you start modifying it with `mprotect`, you should have enough information to restore the previous layout.

The following example shows the contents of `/proc/self/maps` in three scenarios:

- Prior to any operation being performed;
- After a `mmap` (which shows one additional entry in the file); and finally
- After a `mprotect` (which shows the permission bits changing in the file).

(Tested with 32-bit Linux 2.6).

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define PAGE_SIZE 4096

void show_mappings(void)
{
    int a;
    FILE *f = fopen("/proc/self/maps", "r");
    while ((a = fgetc(f)) >= 0)
        putchar(a);
    fclose(f);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    void *mapping;

    /* Show initial mappings. */
    show_mappings();

    /* Map in some pages. */
    mapping = mmap(NULL, 16 * PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    printf("*** Returned mapping: %p\n", mapping);
    show_mappings();

    /* Change the mapping. */
    mprotect(mapping, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE);
    show_mappings();

    return 0;
}
```

As far as I know, there is not mechanism other than the `/proc/` interface that Linux provides to allow you to determine the layout of your virtual memory. Thus, parsing this file is about the best you can do.