# Which sections in memory are writable?

Tags: c, linux, elf

I am running some C code, compiled to 32bit x86 on Linux. And I am trying to access some memory. Apperently I can write to `.bss` and `.data` and to the stack. Some time ago, the [.ctors and .dtors segments used to be writable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8062/dtors-looks-writable-but-attempts-to-write-segfault), but it seems they are gone.

Without trial-and-error, how can I found out to which sections in memory the segments are mapped? How can I find out which addresses are mapped to writable memory and which are executable?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152958/reading-memory-protection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Without trial-and-error, how can I found out to which sections in memory the segments are mapped?

Sections and segments have specific meaning when you talk about `ELF` executables, and your usage above doesn't agree with that meaning.

ELF sections don't matter at load time, only (loadable) segments do.

The `readelf -l a.out` command provides exactly the mapping from ELF sections to segments. E.g.

```
readelf -l /bin/date

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x8048c60
There are 6 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000034 0x08048034 0x08048034 0x000c0 0x000c0 R E 0x4
  INTERP         0x0000f4 0x080480f4 0x080480f4 0x00013 0x00013 R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x08048000 0x08048000 0x05fe0 0x05fe0 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x006000 0x0804e000 0x0804e000 0x00208 0x00334 RW  0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x006078 0x0804e078 0x0804e078 0x000c8 0x000c8 RW  0x4
  NOTE           0x000108 0x08048108 0x08048108 0x00020 0x00020 R   0x4

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00
   01     .interp
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rel.dyn .rel.plt .init .plt .text .fini .rodata
   03     .data .eh_frame .dynamic .ctors .dtors .jcr .got .bss
   04     .dynamic
   05     .note.ABI-tag
```

This tells you that `.ctors` is mapped to segment 3, which is writable (this output is from ancient `UnitedLinux 1.0` distribution).

Nowadays, `.ctors` is put into a segment different from `.data`, and protected from writing after relocation via special `GNU_RELRO` segment.

Answer (score 3):

Look at `/proc/$pid/maps` (or use the `pmap` utility). It'll tell you more than you ever wanted to know about memory regions.